# NGINX server_name field?

Tags: nginx

I want to know what is the usage of server_name field in the nginx i went through the documentation but i didnt understand the exact usage

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 143;
    server_name www.example.com;
    }
  }
```

this means when i try `www.example.com` in any browser runs in port 143.
but when i tried `http://www.example.com:143` it is showing the page cant reached.

Please help me in understanding it

Thanks

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: Have you reloaded nginx configuration after changing your configuration to that? Have you made the proper DNS or Hosts file entry corresponding to `www.example.com` and its IP address?

Comment: Sorry the above snippet i pasted above was the only code i used not other than that , `Have you made the proper DNS or Hosts file entry corresponding to www.example.com and its IP address` Can you please elaborate on that since i am new to this NGINX?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `www.example.com` will not work in browsers because default HTTP port is 80, so `www.example.com` actually is `www.example.com:80`. NGINX will reject your connection to unregistered host.

Check this steps please.

1. Ensure you have in your hosts file (local DNS):

   127.0.0.1 www.example.com
2. Ensure you have specified website root in nginx server config:

   server {
     listen      143;
     server_name www.example.com;
     root        /var/www/wwwexamplecom/public;
   }
3. Ensure you have restarted nginx (command depends on your OS):

   For ubuntu try this:

   sudo service nginx restart / sudo systemctl restart nginx
4. Ensure you use `www.example.com:143` instead of `www.example.com` (described above).

Comment: Thanks.Where i have to specify the host file `127.0.0.1 www.example.com` in my nginx file?

Comment: @C.Yaswanth No, not in nginx file. Hosts file is a special file which contains mappings hostname -> IP address. Please, read an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). You will know what this file is and where is it located on your system.